# problema con dar formato a cadena

Tags: javascript, typescript

¿Como puedo cambiar la primera comilla simple y la ultima por comillas dobles?

para que la salida sea: `"Fire","Air","Water"`

```js
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];

console.log(elements.join('","'));
// Expected output: 'Fire","Air","Water'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes simplemente agregarlas al principio y al final.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];

console.log('"' + elements.join('","') + '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

O podrías añadirlas usando [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) y la sintaxis de [plantilla de cadena](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Por ejemplo:

```js
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];

console.log(elements.map(element => `"${element}"`).join(','));
// Expected output: "Fire","Air","Water"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```